# Printing remaining features in Feature Reduction

Tags: python, printing, dimensionality-reduction

I am running a feature reduction (from 500 to around 30) for a randomforest classifier algo. I can reduce the number of features, but I want to see what features are left at every point in the reduction.As you can see below, I have made an attempt, but does not work.

X does not contain the ColumnNames. Ideally, it could be possible to also have the columnnames in X but only fit from row, then printing X would be possible I think.

I am sure there is a much better way though...

Anybody know how to do this?

```
FEATURES = []
readThisFile = r'C:\ManyFeatures.txt'
featuresFile = open(readThisFile)
AllFeatures = featuresFile.read()
FEATURES = AllFeatures.split('\n')
featuresFile.close()

Location = r'C:\MASSIVE.xlsx'
data = pd.read_excel(Location)

X = np.array(data[FEATURES])    
y =  data['_MiniTARGET'].values 


for x in range(533, 10,-100):
    X = SelectKBest(f_classif, k=x).fit_transform(X, y)
    #U=pd.DataFrame(X)
    #print (U.feature_importances_)
```